# Organise my project folder

Tags: iphone, ios

It's a terrible mess in my project folder (not in xcode, where all is clean, but on the desktop folder).

How can I organize this folder without killing all xcode references ? I just tried, but all the links broke.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I'm used to do in this case is:

1. Organize everything in my finder folders, don't mind the red missing files in xcode. If you are using svn, make sure you use its commands to do this.
2. Then I go to each file in XCode marked red and redefine its Location using the right pane Utilities tab (xcode 4) or its file properties(cmd+i in xcode 3).
3. Clean and build to make sure everything is OK.

To avoid this, I got used to organize my project each time I create a new file/folder. I first create the folder physically and then add it to xcode, later I create the files.

I don't know a simpler way of doing this.

Hope it helps,

Comment: both of your methods were useful, but this one was quicker for me. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

I've been there myself :) You do need to remove and add back in the files that need organizing , but it can be safely done. Here's what I'd normally do;

- Remove the files / folders you need to organize from within your XCode project (this is safe, you can add them back, no worries) ONLY DELETE THE REFERENCES when asked. Do NOT Trash them.
- Close XCode
- In your desktop folder, now arrange and organize your files and folders as needed.
- Open up your XCode again, and open your project. Now, re-add your now well-organized files and folders back into the XCode project. Copy them into to your folder if you happen to be adding anything from outside the desktop folder.
- Now, your project will be well organized both in and outside.